# Issue with HTML <select> tag in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, internet-explorer, html-select

I have this problem. 
I would like to have on internet explorer the same graphic effect I have on google chrome, when I use the Select tag.
For greater clarity I invite you to open this link and notice the select tag's behavior on IE and on google chrome: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select

When I open the dropdown list, I would like to have the list under the box, and I would not to have the position of the list depending on the option I have selected. It is possible in IE?

I hope I was clear, thanks in advance.

Comment: I suggest you a JS scripts to make a custom Select list, like [Select2](https://select2.github.io/), supported by IE8 and up. Since IE and Chrome are different UI's, Select2 will look the same since it uses CSS instead.

Comment: Interesting solution, thanks in the meantime, any other idea is well accepted